# I want to delete a line in txt file

Tags: php

I use `PHP` to read a `txt` file,I read the first line, it is ok.
but when I want to delete the first line.
it fails.....

I can do this code in localhost,but when I boot in server
it fail.....I dont know why...

this is my code:

```
        <?php
    $handle = fopen('newfile.txt', "r");
    $contents = '';
    if ($handle) {
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $contents = fgets($handle, 10);
            echo $contents;

            $filename = 'newfile.txt';
            $content = file_get_contents('newfile.txt');
            $content = str_replace($contents, '', $content);
            file_put_contents('newfile.txt', $content);
            exit;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: ***it always fail.*** How?

Comment: Yeah What means "it always fail." I tried your piece of code and it works fine ?

Comment: Andreas   MorganFreeFarm it fail,I edit

Comment: @解語花 Nope, there is no error in this code, I tried with `.txt` file with 4 rows and it delete first row always.

Comment: Please be explicit: How does your logic fail? The code deletes the first 9 characters (i.e. not the _first line_ perse) of the text in `newfile.txt`. If that is that not your desired outcome; then what is exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the complicated code above ( which I did not check btw ) might be

```
$file='newfile.txt';
$lines=file( $file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
array_shift( $lines );
file_put_contents( $file, implode( PHP_EOL, $lines ) );
```

If it is important to display the line that is being removed then:

```
$file='newfile.txt';
$lines=file( $file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );

$sentence = array_shift( $lines );
echo $sentence;

file_put_contents( $file, implode( PHP_EOL, $lines ) );
```